# How to set normal colors and hovering colors?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Link: jsfiddle.net/d8p00ca5/2/

I want to give icons a certain color(lets say red) and text another color(black).
But when I hover the link, icon and text should have the same color(yellow).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:hover > .fa {
    color:yellow;
}
```

Note, this selector is **very** general and may not be appropriate in all situations.

Alternatively,

```
a.circle:hover > .fa {
    color:yellow;
}
```

Is a little more specific.

[**Jsfiddlde Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8p00ca5/3/)

Comment: You are welcome, If you are inclined you can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `.circle:hover .fa {color:yellow;}`
http://jsfiddle.net/d8p00ca5/4/